# Looking for a more efficient pop count given a restriction

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary, bit-manipulation, hammingweight

The `popcount` function returns the number of 1's in an input. `0010 1101` has a `popcount` of 4.

Currently, I am using this algorithm to get the `popcount`:

```
private int PopCount(int x)
{
    x = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}
```

This works fine and the only reason I ask for more is because this operation is run awfully often and I am looking for additional performance gains.

I'm looking for a way to simplify the algorithm based on the fact that my 1's will always be right aligned. That is, the input will be something like `00000 11111` (returns 5) or `00000 11111 11111` (returns 10).

Is there a way to make a more efficient popcount based on this constraint? If the input was `01011 11101 10011`, it would just return 2 because it only cares about the right-most ones. It seems any kind of looping is slower than the existing solution.

Comment: In other words, you're asking whether a "count leading zeros" (clz) operation is faster than "count all ones" (popcnt)?

Comment: You could calculate it as `trailing_zeroes(~x)`, that would be nice in x86 assembly but in C# that's still annoying. You could try that with the "double hack", but I don't expect much..

Comment: @harold: Or `lg2(x+1)`  There are some fast binary logarithm hacks.

Comment: e.g. https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogLookup or https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightFloatCast

Comment: The count trailing zeros with `~x` looks promising. I'll try benchmarking the difference to see which is preferable.

Comment: Ah, looks like `popcount` is still 5%-10% faster..

Comment: @Ryan: Which exact algorithm did you test?

Comment: @BenVoigt: The one that just does `return Mod37BitPosition[(-v & v) % 37]` given `~v` as an input from https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightModLookup. I'm trying some other ones now. I can't seem to get yours to give the proper output though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74011/discussion-between-ryan-peschel-and-ben-voigt).

Comment: This is also interesting: https://www.klittlepage.com/2013/12/21/twelve-days-2013-de-bruijn-sequences/  I think it's the theory behind the one you tried.  Modulo (%) is obviously going to be pretty slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a C# implementation that performs "find highest set" (binary logarithm).  It may or may not be faster than your current PopCount, it surely is slower than using the real `clz` and/or `popcnt` CPU instructions:

```
static int FindMSB( uint input )
{
    if (input == 0) return 0;
    return (int)(BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(input) >> 52) - 1022;
}
```

Test: http://rextester.com/AOXD85351

And a slight variation without a conditional branch:

```
/* precondition: ones are right-justified, e.g. 00000111 or 00111111 */
static int FindMSB( uint input )
{
    return (int)(input & (int)(BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(input) >> 52) - 1022);
}
```

Comment: I don't think the slight variation works. First one does though.

Comment: You linked test cases with the first one. That one works. The second one doesn't. It gives improper output.

Comment: @Ryan: Fixed test case.  It seems to work: http://rextester.com/SVQYZM40373  I mean, it works on the right-justified ones from the question.

Comment: Try it with 160 as an input.

Comment: @Ryan: Ahh, clarified with a comment.